# kinit unable to connect

Tags: kerberos, apache-ds, mitkerberos

I'm trying to connect to a Kerberos running on ApacheDS. Here is the initial LDIF I've loaded on LDAP:

```
dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
ou: Users
description: Example.Com Users
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=hnelson,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: krb5principal
objectClass: krb5kdcentry
cn: Horatio Nelson
sn: Nelson
uid: hnelson
userPassword: secret
krb5PrincipalName: hnelson@EXAMPLE.COM
krb5KeyVersionNumber: 0
```

Then I have created the following /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
  default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5,des3-cbc-sha1-kd
  default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5,des3-cbc-sha1-kd
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = false
  allow_weak_crypto = yes
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = yes  

[realms]
  EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = localhost:60088
    admin_server = localhost:60088
  }

[domain_realm]
  .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
  example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Now when running kinit to get the kerberos ticket it seems no service is available to process the request:

```
[francesco@localhost kerberos]$ kinit hnelson@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for hnelson@EXAMPLE.COM: 
kinit: A service is not available that is required to process the request while getting initial credentials
```

The Service is however running on port 60088:

```
[francesco@localhost kerberos]$ netstat -an | grep 60088
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:60088         :::*                    LISTEN
```

Finally, here's my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?
Thanks